# R the function vegtrans doss not exist in package labdsv version 2.0, while exist in labdsv 1.8?

Tags: r

I'm studying Numerical Ecology with R written by Daniel. A function `vegtrans` in package labdsv is used in the book, however, I can't use the function. I found this function is available in labdsv 1.8, but now it updated to labdsv 2.0. So which function replaced vegtrans?

I found the function in labdsv 1.8.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/labdsv/versions/1.8-0
But in labdsv 2.0, vegtrans missed.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/labdsv/versions/2.0-1

Comment: First time looking at this but it looks like this is the new function https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/labdsv/versions/2.0-1/topics/abundtrans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/cran/labdsv/commit/d7458d4916450fd8dc33533fb344a6a59f56a073#diff-89046306ee2c38d67089d811c93fa6ba) it would appear function `vegtrans` has become `abundtrans`. Argument name `taxa` has also been changed to `comm`. It's unfortunate that this is not mentioned in the changelog.